# Capture stored procedure output in Teradata BTEQ script

Tags: shell, stored-procedures, teradata

I have the following shell scripts which execute a Teradata stored procedure using BTEQ. The stored procedure returns a varchar called BATCH_KEY. Could you please explain how to:

Capture the output of the stored procedure in the BTEQ script? Pass the output to the shell script? Having the shell script returning the output value itself?

```
echo "Check if number of parameters is correct"
if [ "$#" -ne 4 ]; then
    echo "You must enter exactly 4 command line arguments"
    exit 0
fi

echo "Call bash profile"
source ~/.bash_profile

echo "Setting parameters value for the stored procedure"
in_P_BATCH_OWNER=$1
in_P_ACTION=$2
in_P_START_DATETIME=$3
in_P_END_DATETIME=$4

echo "Logging into Teradata"
Server=server
LoginId=user
Password=password
DbName=db

echo "Calling stored procedure"
bteq<<EOF
.logon ${Server}/${LoginId},${Password};
CALL $DbName.SP_AUDIT_BATCH('$in_P_BATCH_OWNER', '$in_P_ACTION', '$in_P_START_DATETIME', '$in_P_END_DATETIME');
.logoff;
.quit;
EOF

if [ $? == 0 ]
then
   echo "Script executed sucessfully"
   exit 1
else
   echo "Script executed with failure"
   exit 0
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, found thanks to my awesome team members :)

```
echo "Check if number of parameters is correct"
if [ "$#" -ne 4 ]; then
    echo "You must enter exactly 4 command line arguments"
    exit 1
fi

echo "Call bash profile"
source ~/.bash_profile

echo "Setting parameters value for the stored procedure"
in_P_BATCH_OWNER=$1
in_P_ACTION=$2
in_P_START_DATETIME=$3
in_P_END_DATETIME=$4

echo "Logging into Teradata"
Server=server
LoginId=user
Password=password
DbName=db

echo "Calling stored procedure"
bteq<<EOF
.logon ${Server}/${LoginId},${Password};
.export file=/opt/scripts/data_quality/batch_key.txt;
CALL $DbName.SP_AUDIT_BATCH('$in_P_BATCH_OWNER', '$in_P_ACTION', '$in_P_START_DATETIME', '$in_P_END_DATETIME');
.export reset;
.logoff;
.quit;
EOF

if [ $? == 0 ]
then
   echo "BTEQ script executed sucessfully"
   out_P_BATCH_KEY=`tail -1 /opt/scripts/data_quality/batch_key.txt`
   echo "BATCH_KEY=$out_P_BATCH_KEY"
   rm -f /opt/scripts/data_quality/batch_key.txt
   exit $out_P_BATCH_KEY
else
   echo "BTEQ Script executed with failure"
   exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Summary of the answer: To extract the output from the stored procedure first you have created an export file and written all the stuff to that file. Then you have parsed that file and fetched the required data which in this case is present in the last line of the file. After fetching the required data delete the export file.